# AngularJS remote validation with kendo-validator

Tags: angularjs, validation, kendo-ui

I am new in angular-js. I am developing my app with angular-kendo. I followed http://kendo-labs.github.io/angular-kendo/#/Validator

Before implement the in my real project I implement it in my text project. Look at my view:

```
  <form role="form" name="formTimeLine" kendo-validator="validator" 
  k-options="myValidatorOptions">
  <p>{{Welcome}}</p>
   <span class="label required">Name:</span>
  <input type="remarks" name="remarks" class="k-textbox" 
  ng-model="fiscalYear.Remarks" data-test="Please write sabbir."/><br>
   <span data-for='remarks' class='k-invalid-msg'></span>
  <button ng-click="Save()">Save</button>
  </form>
```

My validation rules in controller is as

```
 $scope.myValidatorOptions = {
  rules: {
    test: function (input) {
        if (input.is("[name=remarks]")) {

            return input.val() == "Sabbir"
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
  },
  messages: {
    test: "Your UserName must be Sabbir"
}
};
```

My save function is as follows

```
 $scope.Save = function () {
 if ($scope.validator.validate()) {
    alert("Saved");
 }
 else {
    alert("Error");
 }
 };
```

How can I wire up a rule with kendo-validator so that remote validation will be called and validate? It is said to use custom directive and `ctrl.$setValidity('unique', false);` but calling `$scope.validator.validate()` return true. I want http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/form-validation-the-angularjs-way with kendo-validator.